# How do download an xml from Google Cloud Storage into an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, download, google-cloud-storage

I want to download an xml file into an `XDocument` if that is possible from the Google Cloud Storage.

Here in this code the file is download into a local file Path

```
private void DownloadObject(string bucketName, string objectName,
    string localPath = null)
{
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    localPath = localPath ?? Path.GetFileName(objectName);
    using (var outputFile = File.OpenWrite(localPath))
    {
        storage.DownloadObject(bucketName, objectName, outputFile);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"downloaded {objectName} to {localPath}.");
}
```

Is it possible to put the file into an `Xdocument` instead to be used in the code for xml parsing

**Update**

what I have tried is this but the stream has readTimeOut

```
var storage = StorageClient.Create();
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            storage.DownloadObject("angular-book-app-bucket", "books.xml", stream);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(stream.ToString());
```

I can however create a new bucket with `CreateBucket` so I should be able to read

Image showing readTimeOut 
[image]

Comment: Using XDocument.Load(URL) will down load some xml files when data is not secure.  Other times you have to use a WebClient to send cookies or use certificates.

Comment: I updated my question with some code I try

Comment: If you have a string then use XDocument.Parse(string).  When using a memory stream after you write to the stream you have to set the position property to zero before reading.